# how to refer razor class library in project in blazer application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a razor class library. with in razor class library I am referring mud blazer. when I tried to add reference of Razor class library in client application. am getting mud blazer reference error in blazer application.  [image: attachment]

Please help me on over come issue. leads are appreciated.

[image: attachment]

Answer (score 0):

You can right click your Project and select `Manage Nuget Packages`.
[image]

Then you need to search MudBlazor in Browse,and choose version 5.1.5,and check if the versions in your project is at least 5.0.10.
[image]

If you have installed the package but still have the error.Try to clean the project and reinstall it.

Comment: actually my question was not clear. I have created a razor class library with mudblazer components in it. I am trying to access components in to another blazor application.  when i consume  am getting the error in blazor application.  exposing method in below way showed in screen shot.

Comment: Screen shot added in first comment